# VBScript - image to binary

Tags: image, vbscript, binary

i'm not a VB programmer but i need a vbscript that convert image file (from local disk) to be converted to binary data and the passed to webservice. I realize how to pass data to webservice but i can't find how to convert the image file to binary data. I spend a lot of time to find some kind of solution but with no luck.
Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Base64 encode VBS function (vb encoder algorithm), source code**
http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_Base64Encode/

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to read the image file as binary data (in a way similar to reading text files), you can use the [`ADODB.Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032.aspx) object:

```
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Dim oStream, bData

Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oStream.Type = adTypeBinary
oStream.Open
oStream.LoadFromFile "C:\MyImage.png"

bData = oStream.Read

' Do whatever you need with bData
...
```